# Hammer.js 2 in listen only mode

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

When I specify hammer to capture on the window there is an issue because there is no ownerDocument.

```
function getWindowForElement(element) {
var doc = element.ownerDocument;
return (doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow);
```

}

The reason I do this is because I just want to listen to all the hammer.js events that are happening on the page. If I use document.body which was recommended in hammer.js 1 the default actions of the page are blocked. In hammer.js 1 this was not the case. I could do something like

```
hammertimeArray.push(new Hammer(document.body, gestureOptions));
```

or

```
hammertimeArray.push(new Hammer(window, gestureOptions));
```

What has changed between hammer 1 and 2 that I can no longer listen to events without affecting the page behavior. Is there a way I can do this in hammer 2? Currently what I do is:

```
hammertime = new Hammer.Manager(window);
                    hammertime.add(new Hammer.Tap({event: 'tap'}));
                    hammertime.add(new Hammer.Pan({direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL}));
                    hammertime.add(new Hammer.Press());
                    hammertime.add(new Hammer.Pinch({enable: true}));
                    hammertime.on(eventsToEnable, function hammertimeOnCallback(eventData) {
                            recordEvent(eventData);
                    });
                    hammertimeArray.push(hammertime);
```

If I create the manager with window as the argument as I have done there I run into the documentOwner issue. If I create the manager with document.body then the default actions on the page are blocked. I can hack a solution by setting `window.documentOwner = document`.